# Retreive tweet information (text&image) from timeline in TWTRTimelineViewController - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, twitter, twitterkit

Good afternoon,

I have an app that asks the user to log in thanks to twitter's doc found there: [Log in with twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/log-in-with-twitter). Then, I can successfully load the user's timeline. This timeline loads in a **NavigationController** which has the interface **TWTRTimelineViewController**. Now, I would like that when one user holds his finger on a tweet, or just click on one tweet, rather than opening Safari to display it, it pops up a button where I'll be able to work on the tweet after clicking. I will need to get access to the text and the image of the tweet.
From my understanding, I will need to delegate all the tweets to some kind of **TWTRTweetView** controller to work on them but I'm not so sure how, since I'm completely new to this. I did try to read the doc but couldn't really get it, and most of the example are written in Swift. I'm also not sure how I'm supposed to access the tweet's properties. I have tried **STTwitter** where I played with some JSON formatted texts and where I was able to get the text and the image URL but I can't figure out how to do so directly with **TwitterKit**. Here's my actual code of the controller that display the timeline:

```
#import "TwitterTimelineViewController.h"
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface TwitterTimelineViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *TwitterTableView;
@end

@implementation TwitterTimelineViewController

TWTRUserTimelineDataSource *userTimelineDataSource;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"myConsumerKey" consumerSecret:@"myConsumerSecretKey"];
    
    TWTRAPIClient *APIClient = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] init];
    userTimelineDataSource = [[TWTRUserTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithScreenName:delegate.twitterUsername APIClient:APIClient];
    self.dataSource = userTimelineDataSource;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any help would be awesome!

Cheers,
Theo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. For anyone struggling with the same issue, here the code I wrote. A bit messy but it works.

```
-(IBAction)ShowTweets: (id) sender{

UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;

NSString *tweetToDecryptIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)clicked.tag];

//gets all tweets from current timeline
NSArray *allTweets = self.snapshotTweets;

//look the tweets, get the URL and removes it to get the text only
NSDataDetector *detect = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];

    //gets the single tweet from clicked button
    TWTRTweet *tweet = [allTweets objectAtIndex:(long)clicked.tag];
    NSString *content = tweet.text; //gets the text
    NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:content options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])]; //find the URL

    NSURL *url; //contains the url from the text of the tweet
    NSString *ciph; //text from tweet without the url

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
            url = [match URL];
            ciph = [content substringToIndex:content.length-url.absoluteString.length];
        }
    }

    //Now, ask a JSON answer from twitter of the specific tweet using its ID
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] init];
    NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"id" : tweet.tweetID};
    NSError *clientError;

    NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET" URL:statusesShowEndpoint parameters:params error:&clientError];

    if (request) {
        [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (data) {
                NSError *jsonError;
                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

                //NSLog(@"%@", json);
                //looking for the media_url
                NSString *media = [json valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media"];
                NSArray *urlArray = [media valueForKey:@"media_url_https"];

                //finally getting the url as a string
                NSMutableString * urlOfImageString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                for (NSObject * obj in urlArray)
                {
                    [urlOfImageString appendString:[obj description]];
                }

                //NSLog(@"%@",urlOfImageString);

                //constructing name for image to write in path
                NSString *tweetID = tweet.tweetID;
                NSString *imgName = [tweetID stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
                NSString *tmp = [@"/your/path" stringByAppendingString:imgName];

                //NSLog(@"%@", tmp);

                //Now writting the image
                NSURL *urlOfImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlOfImageString];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOfImageUrl];   
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
    }
```

Comment: How can we do with guest authentication?